# how to find the max number of items in a list such that certain pairs are not together in the output?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I have a list of numbers

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and a list of tuples which describe which items should not be in the output together.

```
gl_distribute = [(1, 2), (1,4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

the possible lists are

```
[1,3]
[2,4,5]
[3,5]
```

and I want my algorithm to give me the second one `[2,4,5]`

I was thinking to do it recursively.
In the first case (t1) I call my recursive algorithm with all the items except the 1st, and in the second case (t2) I call it again removing the pairs from gl_distribute where the 1st item appears.
Here is my algorithm

```
def check_distribute(items, distribute):
    i = sorted(items[:])
    d = distribute[:]
    if not i:
        return []
    if not d:
        return i

    if len(remove_from_distribute(i, d)) == len(d):
        return i

    first = i[0]
    rest = items[1:]
    distr_without_first = remove_from_distribute([first], d)

    t1 = check_distribute(rest, d)

    t2 = check_distribute(rest, distr_without_first)
    t2.append(first)

    if len(t1) >= len(t2):
        return t1
    else:
        return t2
```

The remove_from_distribute(items, distr_list) removes the pairs from distr_list that include any of the items in items.

```
def remove_from_distribute(items, distribute_list):
    new_distr = distribute_list[:]
    for item in items:
        for pair in distribute_list:
            x, y = pair
            if x == item or y == item and pair in new_distr:
                new_distr.remove((x,y))
    if new_distr:
        return new_distr
    else:
        return []
```

My output is `[4, 5, 3, 2, 1]` which obviously is not correct. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here? Or can you give me a better way to approach this?

Comment: what about `4,5`,`5,2` etc... I don't understand your, *possible lists are*

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think *possible lists* means *possible maximal lists* (ie you can't add one more).  And the question is how to find the longest possible maximal list.

Comment: what happens if you have two lists of the same length?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand your output as I think 4,5 and 5,2 should be possible lists as they are not in the list of tuples:

If so you could use itertools to get the combinations and filter based on the `gl_distribute` list using sets to see if any two numbers in the different combinations in combs contains two elements that should not be together, then get the `max`

```
combs = (combinations(l,r) for r in range(2,len(l)))
final = []
for x in combs:
     final += x
res = max(filter(lambda x: not any(len(set(x).intersection(s)) == 2 for s in gl_distribute),final),key=len)

print res
(2, 4, 5)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain the res statement? to much for me to handle :-S

Comment: basically after we get all the combinations we use `set.intersection` which returns common elements between two iterables, if there are two elements in common between  a comb and any tuple in  `gl_distribute` then we don't keep that comb, finally we get the max based on the length of all  the remaining combinations that are left after our filtering

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest an alternative approach.

Assuming your list and your distribution are sorted and your list is length of n, and your distribution is length of m.

First, create a list of two tuples with all valid combinations.  This should be a O(n^2) solution.
Once you have the list, it's just a simple loop through the valid combination and find the longest list.  There are probably some better solutions to further reduce the complexity.

Here are my sample codes:

```
def get_valid():
  seq = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  gl_dist = [(1, 2), (1,4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
  gl_index = 0
  valid = []
  for i in xrange(len(seq)):
   for j in xrange(i+1, len(seq)):
     if gl_index < len(gl_dist):
       if (seq[i], seq[j]) != gl_dist[gl_index] :
         valid.append((seq[i], seq[j]))
       else:
         gl_index += 1
     else:
       valid.append((seq[i], seq[j]))
  return valid 
>>>> get_valid()
[(1, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 5), (4, 5)]
def get_list():
  total = get_valid()
  start = total[0][0]
  result = [start]
  for i, j in total:
    if i == start:
      result.append(j)
    else:
      start = i
      return_result = list(result)
      result = [i, j]
      yield return_result
  yield list(result)
  raise StopIteration
>>> list(get_list())
[[1, 3], [2, 4, 5], [3, 5], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: It works great. At the moment I don't care for the complexity or the fact that two lists might be of the same size.
How about this code to extract the maximum length?
`posible_lists = list(get_list())  

sizes = {len(lst):lst for lst in posible_lists}  

print sizes[max(sizes)]`

Comment: use sorted() is simpler.
Something in the vein of 
    sorted(get_list(), key=len, reverse=True)[0] 
probably is what you needed.